# Restricting to update a field in Entity Data Model in Silverlight

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

I am having a field in the database "IsActive" which is "Null" by default. Now I want to update the field once and set it to true. Now once the field is set to true I need to prohibit further modifications to it. Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

For each property RIA Services creates in an entity, RIA Services also creates several partial method stubs that are called when the property value is changing for you to override, e.g. For your IsActive property, RIA Services generates:

```
    Private Partial Sub OnIsActiveChanging(ByVal value As Boolean)
    End Sub

    Private Partial Sub OnIsActiveChanged()
    End Sub
```

You'll find these stubs in the file that RIA Services creates when you compile (in the Generated_Code folder in your Silverlight project folder; it won't be included in the project itself).

There is no way to "cancel" the change, but you can put a little logic in to set the value back yourself, e.g. in a partial class for your entity:

```
    Private _setBackToTrue As Boolean

    Private Sub OnIsActiveChanging(ByVal value As Boolean)
        If Not value AndAlso Me.IsActive Then
            _setBackToTrue = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnIsActiveChanged()
        If _setBackToTrue Then
            Me.IsActive = True
            _setBackToTrue = False
        End If
    End Sub
```